# Flow Debounce for several types

Tags: android, kotlin, debouncing, kotlin-sharedflow

I have a screen with several switchcompats like on photo.
And I want to collect only last input of each of them to send it to server. I use `SharedFlow`. Now I take last state by `debounce` but it returns only one for all the toggles. How can I use `debounce` or other function on `Flow` so as to collect last state of each of the toggles? I have a unique field in Toggle class to group by.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a data class to hold all the state of the switches. And update the state this data class by the switch's id.

```
data class SwitchesState(
    val switch1:Boolean = false,
    val switch2:Boolean = false,
    val switch3:Boolean = false,
    val switch4:Boolean = false,
    val switch5:Boolean = false
)

class SwitchesViewModel : ViewModel {

    private val _switchesFlow = MutableStateFlow(SwitchesState());
    val switchesFlow:Flow get() = _switchesFlow;

    fun updateSwitch(id:Int, state:Boolean) {
       _switchesFlow.value = when(id) {
          R.id.switch1 -> _switchesFlow.value.copy(swith1 = state)
          R.id.switch2 -> _switchesFlow.value.copy(swith2 = state)
          R.id.switch3 -> _switchesFlow.value.copy(swith3 = state)
          R.id.switch4 -> _switchesFlow.value.copy(swith4 = state)
          else -> _switchesFlow.value.copy(swith5 = state)
        }
    }

}

class SwitchesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState:Bundle) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.switchesFlow.debounce(500).collect {
                // Do something
            }
        }
        
    }

}
```